# Лес какой: пИленый или пилЁный?

Tags: е-или-ё

Цитата из перевода *Унесённых ветром:*

> Она и сейчас — вместо того чтобы ехать на лесопилку — частенько освобождала себе день и торговала **пиленым лесом**.

Смотрим по словарям:

> ПИЛЁНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Распиленный, обработанный пилением. П. лес. **(Ожегов, Шведова)**
>
> пилёный
>   прил.
>   Распиленный на части. **(Ефремова)**
>
> ПИЛЁНЫЙ и (редк.) ПИЛЕНЫЙ, пиленая, пиленое. Распиленный на куски, подвергшийся пилке. Пилёный лес. Пиленая древесина. Пилёный сахар (выработанный ровными прямоугольными плитками, в отличие от колотого). **(Ушаков)**

Правильно я понимаю, что исходно автор имел ввиду:

> Она и сейчас — вместо того чтобы ехать на лесопилку — частенько освобождала себе день и торговала **пилёным лесом**.

Answer (score 6):

В "Новом орфоэпическом словаре" Т.Ф. Ивановой статья:

Пиленный - причастие страдательное прошедшего времени к "пилить", малоупотебительное.

Пилёный - прилагательное.

В Вашем примере - ***пилёный*** лес, где ***пилёный*** - прилагательное, указывающее больше на постоянный признак леса, чем на признак, развивающийся во времени (ср. солёный, варёный). Вы всё понимаете правильно.